# Paragraph footnotes with multicol

Tags: footnotes, multicol

I'm using the following in my document:

```
\documentclass[9.5pt,english,twosides,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[perpage,para,norule]{footmisc}
```

I'm creating footnotes from inside two-column text. I expect the footnotes to appear in a single paragraph at the bottom of the text block, covering the entire text width.

Instead the footnote paragraph is only the width of a single column, and extends downwards about twice as far as desired so that it overlays the page number:

[image]

(You can see the page number 22 buried among the footnotes.)

**What I'd settle for:**

My goal is to have the footnotes fill the bottom of the textblock without leaving much empty whitespace. Ideally the footnote paragraph would spread across the entire text width, but at this stage I'd settle for two columns of footnotes, or footnotes only in one column, or anything similar as long as it doesn't look absurd.

I'm using multicols because some pages need to contain both multicolumn and single column text.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried a number of other approaches, including using `\paragraphfootnotes` instead of the footmisc package, but that looks even worse. I've tried to hack the `\@footnotetext` routine and the `\@makecol` routine to set `\columnwidth` to `\textwidth`, but I don't really know what I'm doing and I've had no success. I understand the multicol package already hacks the `\@footnotetext` routine, so I guess footmisc doesn't use this, or doesn't use it in the normal way.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: "I'm using multicols because some pages need to contain both multicolumn and single column text."

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. (+1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makefootnoteparagraph}
   {\columnwidth}{\textwidth}
   {\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{patch failed}}
```

see answer to question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339187/10109

But as it is mentioned there it is not a general fix for the issue.

Comment: @BenWhitmore Appreciation is better done through upvoting (so that others see the answer helped)