# KOMAScript and multi-column footnotes

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, columns, scrbook

I'm using the `scrbook` KOMAScript class. I have many short footnotes, which would be nicer if they were formatted in multiple columns instead of one long column that leaves a lot of undesired whitespace.

There are a variety of solutions that I've investigated that are incompatible with my setup:

- [dblfnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194584/6324) takes my 130+ page document and turns it into 5000+ page document!
- [rledmac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69620/6324) Creates an error `no room for a new \write` that doesn't happen when this package isn't loaded.
- [use the memoir class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8714/6324) I'm already using `scrbook` from KOMAScript

Several [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437829/6324) are similar, but relate to having multi-column footnotes in a multi-column document. I have a single-column document

Comment: Try  `footmisc` with option `para`. It's not exactly multi-column, but it typesets all footnotes on a page in a single paragraph at the bottom of the page. If there are several footnotes on the page, they will be run together in the page foot, each introduced by its footnote mark. Might be (close to) what you are looking for.

Comment: @Ingmar that certainly makes my footnotes take up less space, but a columnar format would look a little more clean.

Comment: See this thread for more: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134937/split-latex-footnotes-into-two-columns

Comment: I wasn't able to get `dblfnote` to work, but I did finally get the `bidi` package to work. Found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85757/6324) answer at the end of a list of answers.

Comment: Requires `XeLaTeX`, though, so might not be an option for everyone … Glad it works for you.

Comment: It does require XeLaTeX, which I was already using. But perhaps I responded too quickly. For some reason including `bidi` creates the error: `! Missing number, treated as zero.` on a custom counter I have. I'm afraid my setup is a bit fragile.